# Javascript file changes inside the vendor source are not detected in Yii2

Tags: yii2

INTRODUCTION:

1. Application is build on yii2
2. Star rating system is build with "Kartik's star-rating widget"

PROBLEM:

[Image with description of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yil9t.png)

How to make changes in vendor's files of Kartik's widget?

Comment: seems you have a linked library refresh issue .. try releoad them .. (normally a round arrow in browser  url  bar )

Comment: No, I tried it many times, even cleared the browser cache

Comment: thought that the problem is that there are two files with the same name, but did not find the second file (if there is one)

Comment: i can seem tofigure out what the actual problem is are you trying to say that the javascript file changes are not detected ? and are you trying to make those changes inside the `vendor` source files?

Comment: yes the javascript file changes inside the vendor source are not detected.

Comment: delete the contents of /web/assets folder and refresh.

Comment: then add this in your web.php components section: `
        'assetManager' => [
            'appendTimestamp' => true,
        ],`